# Queries add a number, remove a number, replace all A[i] in array with A[i] xor X, find sum of K smallest numbers

Tags: algorithm, xor

The problem is:

> Initially, the sequence is empty. There are n queries and 4 types of queries:
>
> - **Add(x):** add x to the sequence, if there is already x in the sequence, still add x.
> - **Remove(x):** remove x from the sequence 1 times.
> - **Xor(x):** replace all N of the sequence with N xor x.
> - **Sum(K):** find sum of the k smallest elements in the sequence.
> - 0 <= x, n, K <= 10^5
>
> For each query sum(x), output the sum of the x smallest elements in the sequence.
>
> **Input:**
>
> ```
> 7
> Add(4)      // A[] = {4}
> Remove(3)   // A[] = {4}
> Add(2)      // A[] = {4, 2}
> Sum(2)      // A[] = {4, 2} => Output: 6
> Xor(2)      // A[] = {4^2, 2^2} = {6, 0}
> Sum(1)      // A[] = {6, 0} => Output: 0
> Sum(2)      // A[] = {6, 0} => Output: 6
> ```

I solved the problem with the following way:

> Use a vector A to hold the sequence of numbers, and an array Count[] where Count[x] is the number of occurrences of x in A. Initially A is empty, and every Count[x] = 0.
>
> - For each Add(x) query, I add x to A, and Count[x] = Count[x]+1
> - For each Remove(x) query, if Count[x] = 0 then skip, otherwise, remove x from A and Count[x] = Count[x]-1
> - For each Xor(x) query, replace every A[i] with A[i]^x
> - For each Sum(x) query, sort A in ascending value, take the sum of the first x numbers

***It seems that my way has a complexity of O(n^2), so for n <= 100000 the above algorithm cannot work. Is there a better way to solve this problem? Thanks a lot.***

My code can run well in n <= 5000. Here is it:

```
int Count[100001];
vector<int> A;
void Add(int x) {
     A.push_back(x);
     Count[x] = Count[x]+1;
}
void Remove(int x) {
     if (Count[x] == 0) return;
     Count[x] = Count[x]-1;
     auto Find = find(A.begin(), A.end(), x);
     A.erase(Find);
}
void Xor(int x) {
     for (int& i : A)
         i = i^x;
}
int Sum(int x) {
     int Num = 0, S = 0;
     for (int i : A) {
        if (Num + 1 > x) return S;
        S = S + i; Num = Num + 1;
     }
     return S;
}
```

Comment: What's the constraint on k?

Comment: @גלעדברקן I guess total queries are 10^5 and size of max array is 10^5 .. means k will always be less than < 10^5 ... hope you got the issue in your soln.

Comment: You could keep the array sorted at all times, i.e., add will search for the first element >= itself. Then you only have to take the x first elements for `sum`. So `sum` becomes simple and `remove` and `add` have to search. But both will be linear.

Comment: @BenjaminMaurer linear is the issue we can't do linear updates & search every time it will be almost approximately O(n^2). After thinking too much I can say if we are able to remove the O(n) from any 2-3 types queries we are able to pass the soln.  (min heap instead of simple arrayList/ vector )[maybe i am wrong].

Comment: @גלעדברקן k <= 10^5 too. It's a large number to solve in O(n^2) :(

Comment: @adarsh Thank you. That's right. k <= 10^5

Comment: @BenjaminMaurer Thank you. That's good for Add, Remove and Sum queries but isn't for Xor :( We have to replace all A[i] by A[i]^X, it takes O(n) and there are n queries so it's still O(n^2) too :(

Comment: @don'ttalkjustcode Yes. Find sum of k smallest number is "Sum(k)". It's my spelling mistake. Thank you.

Comment: Would you consider adding the working code to update the readers?

Comment: Where is the problem from? Is it online somewhere for testing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'll describe a data structure that supports `Add(x)/Remove(x)/Count()/SumXorWith(x)` (returns the sum of all elements xor `x`; doesn't modify the sequence) and then sketch how to extend it to a full solution where each operation is `O(log^2 n)` (taking `n` to be both the number of operations and the upper bound on the values).

First observe that `Count` and `SumXorWith` can be used to count, for each bit position, how many numbers have that position set (e.g., for the low order bit, it's `(Count() + SumXorWith(0) - SumXorWith(1)) / 2`). Conversely, it's enough to maintain these counts. In pseudocode:

```
*** Variables, initially zero:

count : int
bit_count : int[17]

*** Operations:

Add(x):
increment count
for j from 0 to 16, add the j'th bit of x to bit_count[j]

Remove(x):
decrement count
for j from 0 to 16, subtract the j'th bit of x from bit_count[j]

Count():
return count

SumXorWith(x):
return the sum for j from 0 to 16 of
2**j * (if j'th bit of x = 0 then bit_count[j] else count - bit_count[j])
```

To extend this data structure to handle `Xor(x)/Sum()`, we could just take `count - bit_count` for each bit set in `x`, but for efficiency (that we'll need later), there's a trick. The idea is that we store the sequence xor `cum_xor`. More pseudocode:

```
*** Additional variable, initially zero

cum_xor : int

*** Operations:

Add(x): super.Add(x xor cum_xor)
Remove(x): super.Remove(x xor cum_xor)
Xor(x): cum_xor <- cum_xor xor x
Count(): return super.Count()
Sum(): return super.SumXorWith(cum_xor)
```

Finally, we need to handle `Sum(x)`, with selection. This is, frankly, the tedious part. We set up a height-17 (ceiling of log2(100000)) trie on big-endian bit patterns, with one of the data structures above at each node of the trie. To `Add/Remove`, we descend the trie, doing `Add/Remove` at each node. `Xor` we handle as before, by updating `cum_xor`. `Sum(x)` is the trickiest, of course. Starting at the root of the trie, we examine the current node. If it has at most `x` elements, just sum it. Otherwise, its "favored" child is the one that agrees with `cum_xor`, and its "disfavored" child is the one that disagrees. If the favored child has at least `x` elements, then we can operate recursively on it and ignore the disfavored child. Otherwise, we sum the whole favored child and operate recursively on the disfavored child, decreasing `x` by the number of elements in the favored child.

(For maximum practical efficiency, we'd want something with higher fan-out than the trie and likely the naive implementation near the leaves, but this is as simple as I can make it and likely fast enough.)